# How to connect wireless clients to different physical subnets via a single access point but ensure traffic between subnets remains segmented

Tags: wifi, subnet, pfsense, access-point

I’m trying to design a network with a pfSense Firewall / Router. In pfsense I have created four subnets that reside on separate physical ports (not VLANS) on the pfSense hardware:

[image]

The idea will be that these are segmented networks that are strictly controlled with how they communicate with each other for security based on firewall rules. For example insecure IOT devices will be on their own network and can’t communicate with more important devices on different subnets. I haven’t created the firewall rules yet so haven't fully decided on how these subnets are set up.

Here is a rough diagram of how I think my network should be. I’ve colour coded it to represent each distinct subnet. Please note solid coloured lines are hardwired Ethernet devices and dotted coloured lines are wireless devices.

[image]

As you can see I have a main managed switch that has a UnFi wireless access point connected to it as well as other switches in the SEC (Blue) and LAN (Green) networks that will both have some wired devices.

My question is how can I connect wireless devices to one access point such that the wireless access point contains / segments the traffic from that wireless device to the correct physical subnet port on my pfSense firewall and doesn’t mix with traffic from a wireless device that’s on a different subnet? Of course how the subnets communicate with each other will be based on the firewall rules of pfSense, which I have yet to implement.

For example If I had a phone connect to that wireless access point on my LAN (Green) network and I had a printer connect to the same AP on my IOT (Red) network how could I ensure that they can both connect to the wireless access point while also making sure that traffic is segmented based on firewall rules?

I’m very new to networking but I think I have heard a managed switch can achieve this with hard wired devices where you can control where traffic goes on each port. I’m not if this would work with wireless traffic coming from a wireless access point though.

I have seen [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/WMyz7SVlrgc?t=867) where someone set up different SSIDs on a single access point so that wireless devices on different subnets connect to different SSIDs then on the access point they created different VLANs that are attached to each of the SSIDs to segment each SSID but I'm not sure if this could help me as my segmented networks all connect to different physical ports on the pfSense firewall instead of multiple VLANs on one physical port.

I’m not sure how I should go about implementing this. But the overall idea is that I want different segmented networks for different purposes that are strictly controlled with firewall rules but be able to have wireless devices connect to one wireless access point which connects to a main managed switch and ensure the traffic is segmented regardless if it’s wireless or wired.

Comment: I believe this should be as simple as segmenting the SSIDs into VLANs, then using the switch to "split" the VLANs into physical ports. I can't tell you exactly how to do it on your switch, but it should be possible to put the port with the AP in a trunk mode that accepts tagged VLAN frames, and directs them to the correct port for that VLAN

Comment: What AP do you have? Commonly you create a number of SSID's and a number of VLAN's.

Comment: @vidarlo The network diagram says Unifi U6 pro, and I believe the linked tutorial goes through exactly what you describe, but OP wants to know about the config in the switch to glue the VLANs from the AP to the ports on the firewall

Comment: @RobM I'm kind of new to all this so it's confusing to me. I was under the impression mixing VLANs and physical subnets would break things. I'm not even sure what the capabilities of a managed switch are, but I intend to buy a Ubiquti Lite 16 POE for the main managed switch. Correct me I'm wrong but are you saying I should only need to create VLANs on the AP for each SSID, then using the managed VLAN aware switch to view the VLAN tags coming from the AP traffic then doing some sort of port management to segment the AP traffic to the correct physical ports?

Comment: And to add to that I shouldn't need to replicate these VLANs on the pfSense router? And I'm not sure if I could do what you said with a Ubiquti Lite 16 POE. It's not obvious on their product page if it's a managed switch.

Comment: @SneakyShrike yeah spot on, the ethernet frames going between the AP and the switch will carry a VLAN 'tag', just a header field that says "i'm part of VLAN X" and the switch will be configured to strip that tag off, and forward it to the physical port/s that correspond with that VLAN. If you want to share what switch you're using and I can find a manual I could write out some instructions to do that

Comment: If you're using your switch to deal with your VLANs then the pfsense box need know nothing about them, but to be honest you might be able to simplify your wiring a little bit by using tagged VLANs between the switch and router too. If you don't need the 3 cables, maybe for bandwidth or something, you could replace the 3 parallel cables in your diagram with one

Comment: @RobM Hi again, I've took your advice and I've redesigned the network to use VLANs on a single physical LAN. I did a bit more research and they seem secure enough to use in place of separate physical connections. My fear before was that VLANs weren't as secure in terms of isolation. But the hardware savings are great. I've also done a bit more research into switches and have more of an understanding of how trunking and allocating ports to VLANs works. So I intend to stick with VLANs and trunking between AP's and switches. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RobM The switch I was thinking of getting is the Ubiquiti USW-Lite-8-POE (52W) or the 16 port variant of that. I think it should be able to do the job  based on reviews. I haven't bought any of the hardware yet, I'm just trying to simulate it in GNS3 beforehand so I know what i'm doing when it comes to the real install.

Comment: @SneakyShrike Of course tagged VLANs don't provide any kind of encryption or authentication, but as long as your clients are only accessing the network through a device that enforces the separation (the AP, switch, and router will all do this, properly configured) it should be just as secure as physically separate cables. I don't know how to configure VLANs on ubiquiti switches, but I've always found their hardware very easy to configure